# How to access the configuration parameters from the model layer in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to access the configuration parameters in *config.yml* from the model layer? From the controller I can use `$this->container->getParameter('xyz')`. But how can it be done from a class in the Model layer?

Answer (score 6):

In symfony2 Entities are designed as POPOs, meaning that they shouldn't really have access to anything outside of their scope.

If you need some config option in one of your entities, consider passing it as a parameter from the controller like so:

```
$entityName->methodName($param1, $this->container->getParameter('xyz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could (will) break DIC pattern, but you could use a singleton class to "globalize" what you need.

To feed your globals, use `boot`method from Bundle class (where you can access DIC stuff hence configuration).

Or more simple, add a static field to your Entity.

Quick & dirty solution, don't abuse it ;-)

Answer (score -5):

You can use Dependency Injection and add your model to your services.yml file, and like every other service you make you can provide other services as constructor parameters. The only downside is you call `$derp = $this->get("your_service_name");` instead of `$derp = new Derp();`.

For example:

```
    # src/Derp/LolBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
    services:
        derp:
            class:        \Derp\LolBundle\Entity\Message
            arguments:    [@service_container]
```

`@service_container` is a service found using `php app/console container:debug`. It will function identically to `$this->container` in your controllers and it is provided to the constructor of your class. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for more information on how to use service containers.

As previously mentioned they are POPOs (Plain Old PHP Objects) and the previous method of dependency injection is poor choice simply because you will have to remember to provide your model entity with the same object every time you use it (which is a hassle) and Symfony2 services are a way to mitigate that pain.

Comment: Thank you, this is a clean solution

Comment: If this is the answer you were seeking please mark it as such (for others to notice as well).

Comment: Giving the parameter by hand is the best solution. Having an entity in the DIC is wrong because Doctrine2 won't use the DIC to create new entities, but will instanciate them like any POPO.